# Strange error in AVX loop vectorization

Tags: c++, simd, avx

When I try to unroll simplest loop with AVX, I get runtime error - **Segmentation fault**:

```
    const int sz = 9;
    float *src   = (float *)_mm_malloc(sz*sizeof(float), 16);
    float *dest  = (float *)_mm_malloc(sz*sizeof(float), 16);

    for(int i=0; i<8; i+=8)
    {
         __m256 buffer = _mm256_load_ps(src+i);
         _mm256_store_ps(dest+i, buffer);
    }

    _mm_free(src);
    _mm_free(dest);
```

Interesting: if **sz**=8, or >=13, runtime not crushes. Otherwise **segmentation fault** occurs.

What's wrong?

Compiler - gcc 4.7.

Comment: What compiler is this (guessing Intel), is there a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762)?

Comment: Your AVX register contain 256bits. And 256 / 8 = 32, which is why 32 byte alignment is is required when using the intrinsics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising the alignment to 32 makes the symptom go away.

I'm not well versed with these intrinsics, but I wouldn't be surprised if `32`-byte alignment were required on 64-bit CPUs

```
#include <mm_malloc.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main()
{
    const int sz = 9;
    float *src   = (float *)_mm_malloc(sz*sizeof(float), 32);
    float *dest  = (float *)_mm_malloc(sz*sizeof(float), 32);

    for(int i=0; i<8; i+=8)
    {
         __m256 buffer = _mm256_load_ps(src+i);
         _mm256_store_ps(dest+i, buffer);
    }

    _mm_free(src);
    _mm_free(dest);
}
```